# Magento error SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8346-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

This week we got two messages in Magento from orders that went wrong, the message is:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8346-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Does someone know how to fix this. We are using Magento 1.6.1.0

Here is a bit more info about the problem:

since this saterday we get by most of the orders that are placed in the shop the following message by email:SQLSTATE[23000]:

Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8346-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY' every time the message is the same and only the entry key '8346-0-1' is different.

We do not see more details, only the emails we get and then the payment and checkout is not working correct. A couple of examples are:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '14719-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '14719-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '14719-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: can you share some more error details?

Comment: Dear Rajiv, since this saterday we get by most of the orders that are placed in the shop the following message by email:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '8346-0-1' for key 'PRIMARY' every time the message is the same and only the entry key '8346-0-1' is different. We do not see more details, only the emails we get and then the payment and checkout is not working correct

Comment: Usually, this is due to a dud underpowered server. MySQL tries to save a record, the record save happens but the key autoincrement fails. The next record is attempting to be saved with the previous key and so duplicate records are detected. You have to hunt down the record referenced by the key and delete it or increment the key by one so the next record can be created. After having this happen a few times, you will realize the need for more server resources and MySQL optimization so this stops happening.

Comment: Dear Fiasco, Thanks for your reply. We are not that known with hunting down the keys, how can we find the duplucated key in our database. Is this a standard table where it is saved?

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Facing the EXACT same issue. Coen, did you find a solution for this issue yet? Be glad to know how you solved this!

Answer (score 0):

I guess is in order confirmation?? If i guess right it means You are inserting to database an item, already exists, or combination of table columns already existing, and they MUST be UNIQUE.

You can fix it only by the correction of DB insert command.

You can check if you not inserting the same line to the database twice in one script.

Comment: Martin, what would the command look like? You are right this is in the order confirmation and when this happens the order is not placed. Would it also be a fix to change the order and invoice number or is it something else then the order number?